# using special characters in bash variables / array

Tags: bash, osx-snow-leopard

I'm having issues declaring all printable characters in an array in a bash script. I’d like to display all printable characters through a loop 4 times.

Example

```
array=( a b c d … z A B C … Z 1 2 3 … 0 ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ +)

For chr1 in ${array[@]} 
Do
For chr2 in ${array[@]}
Do 
Echo $chr1$chr2
Done
Done
```

I've been able to get the space character to print with using ${array[value of space]} but I still haven't been able to get the * character to print. It tends to print a list of files for some reason.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 5):

Quotes! More quotes!

```
array=( a b c d z A B C Z 1 2 3 0 '!' '@' '#' '$' '%' '^' '&' '*' '(' ')' '_' '+')

for chr1 in "${array[@]}"
do
  for chr2 in "${array[@]}"
  do 
    echo "$chr1$chr2"
  done
done
```

Slap quotes around the special characters in your array declaration, and slap double quotes around the variable accesses in the loops.

Comment: single quotes didn't work and doubles didn't help either. Same result either way.

Answer (score 4):

In shell scripts, quoting is your friend.  Always.

```
array=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m z A B C Z 1 2 3 0 \! \@ \# \$ \% \^ \& \* \( \) _ +)
for chr1 in "${array[@]}"; do
  for chr2 in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$chr1$chr2"
  done
done
```

Works fine here.

Comment: for some reason even if i escape the * with \ "\*" it still prints the files. 

Could this be a problem with my using Mac OS?

Answer (score 1):

```
chr () { printf "\\$(($1/64*100+$1%64/8*10+$1%8))"; }
ord () { printf '%s' "$(( ( 256 + $(printf '%d' "'$1"))%256 ))"; }

for i in {32..126}
do
    for j in {32..126}
    do
        chr $i; chr $j
        echo
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

the `*` is a special character to bash.

> wild card [asterisk]. The * character serves as a "wild card" for filename expansion in globbing. By itself, it matches every filename in a given directory.

From the absolute bash scripting guide[1], you'll want to escape it like the first answer does.

[1] http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Comment: escaping the * with \* still prints a list of files in my directory.